# How Can I print values that are larger than X in a certain Column in a CSV file.?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to take a column of the Csv file and trying to print out any of the numbers that are larger than the Standard deviation x3.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/aaronhuang/Desktop/ffp/exfileDATA.csv', usecols=[1], header=0)
stand = round(df.std(), 2)
print(df)
conf = stand * 3
print(round(conf, 2))
for rogue in df:
if df <= conf:
    print(df)
```

When this is run, it gives out:

```
 Magnitude 
0         19.472
1         19.445
2         19.484
3         19.157
4         19.376
...          ...
6096      19.063
6097      19.178
6098      19.386
6099      19.092
6100      19.191

[6101 rows x 1 columns]
Magnitude     0.42
dtype: float64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aaronhuang/PycharmProjects/EXTTEst/Code sandbox.py", line 12, in <module>
    if df <= conf:
  File "/Users/aaronhuang/.conda/envs/EXTTEst/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1478, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), 
a.any() or a.all().

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can fix this?
Thanks

Comment: want to find the magnitute less the conf try this, ```print(df[df.Magnitude <= conf])```, remove the for loop

Comment: You are trying to compare data frame with the magnitude value. In the if condition on line 12 try df.Magnitude <= conf: # rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re missing two steps, and a final detail:

1. You want to make your `<= conf` evaluation with a pd.Series, not a pd.DataFrame. That is the source of the particular error you’re getting. Assuming the column you’re using is named `‘Magnitude’` then the evaluation should be `df[‘Magnitude’] <= conf’`.
2. That evaluation doesn’t return a filtered DataFrame. Instead, it returns a Boolean pd.Series—a column of data where every element in the column is a `True` or `False` depending on how the element in `’Magnitude’` evaluated in the `<= conf` expression. We can use this Boolean Series as an indexer to actually filter the DataFrame, though, to get the results we want by placing the precious expression inside the DataFrame indexer syntax: `df[df[‘Magnitude’] <= conf]’
3. Finally, to print this filtered data, simply place all of it inside a `print()` command. Final form:

```
print(df[df[‘Magnitude’] <= conf])
```

Comment: Hey I have added the print command but it now prints:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aaronhuang/PycharmProjects/EXTTEst/Code sandbox.py", line 13, in <module>
    if df.Magnitude <= conf:
  File "/Users/aaronhuang/.conda/envs/EXTTEst/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5274, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Magnitude'

Comment: You’ll want to replace ‘Magnitude’ with whatever your column name actually is. ‘Magnitude’ was just my guess based on the code that was posted.

Answer (score 0):

assign z-scores to the dataframe, and the check will be a breeze.

```
df['zscore'] = (df['Magnitude'] - df['Magnitude'].mean())/df['Magnitude'].std(ddof=0)


df_outliers=df[df['zscore']>3]
for rogue in df_outliers:
    print(rogue)
```

Or simply:

```
df_outliers
```